# Defining the associativity of a custom operator in Haskell

Tags: haskell, operators, infix-operator

I'm playing around with custom operators, `infix`, `infixl` and `infixr`. Now I'm confused.

I've written a custom operator for list-multiplication, and thought, that declaring it as a simple infix-operator with no directional associativity, would automatically provide both cases, `nr * list` and `list * number`, as they can be interchanged at will.

```
import Prelude hiding ((*))

infix 6 *

(*) :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
n * l = if n < 0 then [] 
                 else l ++ (n - 1) * l
```

Now, `3 * [1, 2, 3]` returns `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]` as expected, but `[1, 2, 3] * 3` throws an error, because I never explicitly defined `list * nr`.

My question: What is the unique functionality of `infix` and why not allways use `infixl` or `infixr` instead, as it should make no difference?

---

I understand "no directional associativity" / `infix` as a synonym to "is commutative":

`a + b + c` has no directional associativity and is commutative and can be written as `(a + b) + c`, `a + (b + c)`, `b + a + c`, `(b + a) + c`, and so on...

For my example `2 * [1, 2] * 1` is the same as `1 * (2 * [1, 2])`, and all other combinations of that, so i dont really get, why there is no implicit reshaping for commutative operator declarations, even with different typed operands.

Comment: You misunderstand the term "associativity". It means not the order of the arguments for a single operator, but the order of evaluating multiple operators in a row, such as `a * b * c`

Comment: 'I understand "no associativity" as a synonym to "is commutative":' That's incorrect. 
"Not associative" means that `(a * b) * c != a * (b * c)`. Commutative means that `a * b == b * a`.

Comment: Assocativity and commutativity are orthogonal properties. An operator can be both (integer addition), neither (integer subtraction), associative-only (matrix multiplication) or commutative-only (...I'm blanking on an example, if there are any)

Comment: I looked up the definitions for associativity and commutativity for + and *. They're both smth like: "The order of operations is irrelevant", only the examples are different. From my point of view the idea of commutativity being synonymous with associativity does still stand for this case.

Comment: @chepner xnor (aka `(==) @Bool`) is commutative but not associative.

Comment: @xtay2 Look them up again, and read them carefully. Your "something like" phrase is something that is supposed to be an intuition, but the English is imprecise and only the math actually matters. You will find that chepner is correct: commutativity and associativity are not the same thing.

Comment: @DanielWagner XNOR seems to be associative. Did you mean NAND or NOR?

Comment: @chepner Whoops, you're absolutely right! My brain short-circuited. nand and nor are commutative but not associative, and xnor is both commutative and associative.

Comment: `infix` does not mean "no directional associativity", it means "no associativity".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fixity declarations only affect parsing, not the definitions of the operators.

If you use `infixl`, then `a * b * c` is parsed as `(a * b) * c`.

If you use `infixr`, then `a * b * c` is parsed as `a * (b * c)`.

If you use `infix`, then you are saying that `a * b * c` cannot be parsed; you *must* use parentheses to specify whether you mean `(a * b) * c` or `a * (b * c)`. Compare

```
Prelude> infix 6 ***; (***) = (+)
Prelude> 1 *** 2 *** 3

<interactive>:8:1: error:
    Precedence parsing error
        cannot mix ‘***’ [infix 6] and ‘***’ [infix 6] in the same infix expression
Prelude> infixl 6 ***; (***) = (+)
Prelude> 1 *** 2 *** 3
6
```

In your case, `*` is not fully associative, because the types don't line up. It can be right-associative, because `3 * (6 * [])` typechecks but not left-associative because `(3 * 6) * []` does not. Using `infix`, you disallow `3 * 6 * []`. If you used `infixr`, then you could write that and the parser will treat it as `3 * (6 * [])`.

---

Making an operator like this *commutative* is tricky, because at the type level they are two different operators. That's easy enough to define:

```
-- Ignoring the fact that both of these operators are already
-- used by the Applicative class for different purposes.

(*>) :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
0 *> l = []
n *> l = l ++ (n-1) * l

(<*) :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
(<*) = flip (*>)
```

Making `*` work as both `Int -> [a] -> [a]` and `[a] -> Int -> [a]` is tricky, if not impossible. (Maybe something involving a multi-parameter type family?

```
-- Compiles, but does not run. Not sure why...
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleContexts #-}

class Multiplable x y where
  type Result x y
  (***) :: x -> y -> Result x y

instance Multiplable Int [a] where
   type Result Int [a] = [a]
   0 *** l = []
   n *** l = l ++ ((n - 1) *** l)

instance Multiplable [a] Int where
  type Result [a] Int = [a]
  l *** 0 = []
  l *** n = l ++ (l *** (n - 1))
```

)

---

Your understanding of associativity and commutativity is incorrect. "Not associative" is not a synonym for "commutative". In fact, the two properties are orthogonal: a given operator can be both, or neither, or only one of the two.

- Integer addition is associative and commutative.
- Integer subtraction is neither associative nor commutative.
- Matrix multiplication is associative, but not commutative. (`BA` can be different from `AB` or even undefined altogether.)
- The NAND operation (the negation of logical AND) is commutative, but not associative:

  ```
  (True NAND True) NAND False == False NAND False == True
  True NAND (True NAND False) == True NAND True == False
  ```

Comment: "If you use infix, then you are saying that a * b * c cannot be parsed". 

Really? Doesn't that just have the same effect as left associativity, as operations are read from left to right?

Comment: No. Using *no* fixity declaration makes the operator default to left-associativity, just as if you used `infixl`, but using `infix` explicitly prevents the parser from guessing.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know, what the default rank of a self-defined operator is? I'd guess 0, right?

Comment: Nevermind found it: "If the digit is omitted, level 9 is assumed. Any operator lacking a fixity declaration is assumed to be infixl 9" in https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html